# как подсчитать количество записей в таблице с группировкой по полю

Tags: sql

есть таблица director (id, name) и movie (id, name, directorid, year).
Задача вывести всех директоров, снявших более 3-ех фильмов.
Пробую так:

```
SELECT * FROM director WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM movie WHERE movie.directorid = director.id) > 3
```

Правильно ли я делаю?

Comment: В общем случае нет. Представь, что в таблице лежит три записи-копии одного и того же фильма.

Answer (score 2):

Не совесем правильно. Сделайте так:

```
SELECT * FROM director 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT directorid
    FROM movie 
    GROUP BY directorid
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 3
    )
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM director WHERE id IN (SELECT directorid FROM movie GROUP BY directorid HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 3)
Вот так наверное, правильно понял?

Comment: Да, поправил. Спасибо!